# Find an analytic extension for $f(z) = \sqrt{1-z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an adapted version of the question 14, section 2, chapter 3 of Conway's complex analysis book.

**Question:** Consider the principal branch of $\log$, defined for $\mathbb{C} - \mathbb{R}_-$, and define the function
$$ f(z) =\exp \left(\dfrac{1}{2} \log (1-z^2 ) \right)$$
For all $z\in M:=\mathbb{C}-\{w\in\mathbb{C}; 1-w^2 <0\}$

What is the maximal extension such that $f(z)$ is continuous? What is the maximal extension such that $f(z)$ is analytic?

**End of the question.**

**Comments:**
We have $f(z)^2 =1-z^2$ for $z\in M$.

For the ponts $x=\pm1$, I saw that there is an continuous extension to $x$. Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset M$, such that $x_n\to 1$. Then $ 1-x_n^2 \to 0 \implies f(x_n)^2 \to 0 \implies f(x_n)\to 0$, so defining $F(1):=0$ is sufficient. But the main problem still remaining.